# Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server 2008 with the following error

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am using Team Foundation Server 2008. Recently I have changed the application pool identity from custom account to built in account. Now it is giving me the following error:

```
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 4/27/2012 5:52:04 AM
Machine: 'Machine name'
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/469237383/ROOT/Services-2-129799795235444094
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 2044
  Thread Id: 4912
  Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Detailed Message: TF30059: Fatal error while initializing web service
Web Request Details
    Url: http://172.27.88.65:8080/Services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx [method: POST]
    User Agent: Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 10.0.40219.1)
    Headers: Content-Length=354&Content-Type=text%2fxml%3b+charset%3dutf-8&Accept-Encoding=gzip%2cgzip%2cgzip&Accept-Language=en-US&Authorization=NTLM+TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAIQAAABAAUABnAAAAAwADABYAAAAEAAQAGQAAAAQABAAdAAAAAAAAADcAQAABYKIogYBsB0AAAAPzNwMcCQoNj5DllXRL0wQ9UMAWQBCAEEARwBFAHIAbwBoAGkAdABzAGgAZQBSAE8ASABJAFQAUwBIAEUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAScCbf7HgE8WxhKm6b8N1LgEBAAAAAAAAQrHr3jkkzQEnHfSqYiSa%2fgAAAAACAAwAQwBZAEIAQQBHAEUAAQAUAEcAQQBOAEUAUwBIAC0AMgBLADgABAAUAGMAeQBiAGEAZwBlAC4AYwBvAG0AAwAqAEcAYQBuAGUAcwBoAC0AMgBrADgALgBjAHkAYgBhAGcAZQAuAGMAbwBtAAUAFABjAHkAYgBhAGcAZQAuAGMAbwBtAAcACABCseveOSTNAQYABAACAAAACAAwADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwAACCWwxwe013jUfTNQ2MjXw%2fCVKipQ1WGA3q2%2fqyv%2fU74QoAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACQAiAEgAVABUAFAALwAxADcAMgAuADIANwAuADgAOAAuADYANQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%3d&Expect=100-continue&Host=172.27.88.65%3a8080&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe%2c+10.0.40219.1)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-TFS-Session=1b868cb2-92a4-40ac-ae65-f176904d53e5&SOAPAction=%22http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2fTeamFoundation%2f2005%2f06%2fServices%2fServerStatus%2f03%2fCheckAuthentication%22
    Path: /Services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx
    Local Request: False
    Host Address: 172.27.88.75
    User: CYBAGE\rohitshe [authentication type: NTLM]

Exception Message: TF30041: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database.  Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator. (type DatabaseConnectionException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Global.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.TeamFoundationApplication.Init()

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Cannot open database "TfsIntegration" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. (type SqlException)
SQL Exception Class: 11
SQL Exception Number: 4060
SQL Exception Procedure: 
SQL Exception Line Number: 65536
SQL Exception Server: GANESH-2K8
SQL Exception State: 1
SQL Error(s):
SQL Error[1]: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.
    Class: 14
    Number: 18456
    Server: 'Machine Name'
    Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
    State: 1
    Procedure: 
    Line Number: 65536

Exception Data Dictionary:
HelpLink.ProdName = Microsoft SQL Server
HelpLink.EvtSrc = MSSQLServer
HelpLink.EvtID = 4060
HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
HelpLink.LinkId = 20476


Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.RegistrationDataAccessor.GetRegisteredTools(String toolId, String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.RegistrationDataAccessor.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId, String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.RegistrationEventSchemaProvider..ctor(String applicationPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.CombinationEventSchemaProvider..ctor(String applicationPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Global.Initialize()
```

What could be the problem and how could I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message looks like you are trying to connect to the TFS database with the Network service user. This is your builtin account. So the "Website" TFS is using it's service user to connect to DB.

Btw: did you install latest SP for TFS?

You might change the user running the TFS service or any other user with enough access rights to TFS db.
Which IIS Version do you use?

I do not have a TFS running here anymore but in IIS 7 you should find an application pool for the TFS sites and in advanced settings you can change the Identity of the Process Model.